# Refused to get unsafe header "ETag"

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm using azure Mobile service version "MobileServices.Web-1.1.5.min.js" and when I update a table in database im getting this error on the debug console ("CHROME")

```
> Refused to get unsafe header "ETag" MobileServices.Web-1.1.5.min.js:2
> getItemFromResponse MobileServices.Web-1.1.5.min.js:2 (anonymous
> function) MobileServices.Web-1.1.5.min.js:2 c
> MobileServices.Web-1.1.5.min.js:2 (anonymous function)
> azureService.js?bust=1400282269337:10 r.onreadystatechange
```

this did not happened with the older version of the MobileServices.

How to correct this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't do anything to correct it.

This error is browser implementation dependent and you can safely ignore it. It has to do with CORS configuration in Mobile Services. When the update to the table completes successfully, MobileServices sends the updated object back in the response.  One of the response headers is "ETag" which some browsers/versions mistakenly identify as dangerous. As far as I know there is nothing you can do to make the console error go away via your code.

If you run the same exact code in Firefox, you will not get the error.

Answer (score 1):

You **may** just create a PHP "proxy" that uses `cURL` or `file_get_content` to fetch the remote content.

You may add the headers `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` or replace the `*` with your domain-name(s). Last thing is the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` that limits the exposure of headers,

for example if you choose to response with `access-control-expose-headers:Client-Protocol`- your **JavaScript based `xhr` object** *(for example)*

-- calling for `xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()` will give you `pragma, content-type, cache-control, expires` *(if any exist)*, skipping few more useful such as `Content-Length` and `X-...` ones.. :(